# Software center won't open

Tags: release-freya, appcenter

I'm running Freya and I get the following error messages when I try to run the software center from the command line:

```
    ** (software-center:2639): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-eEmyMEyVbj: Connection refused
2015-11-19 10:34:11,388 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 130, in <module>
    app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 407, in __init__
    self.icons)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/historypane.py", line 79, in __init__
    self._get_emblems(self.icons)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/historypane.py", line 199, in _get_emblems
    pb = icons.load_icon(emblem, self.ICON_SIZE, 0)
gi._glib.GError: Error opening file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried fixes from the following sources:

- [Software center does not open after update](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2707/software-center-does-not-open-after-update/2800#2800)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/3nb7ep/software_center/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/3rphcc/is_anyone_else_having_problems_with_the_software/
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/numix-icon-theme-circle/+bug/1268871

None of them have worked. As a workaround I have synaptic package manager installed but I'm not a fan of it. I have a co-worker running the same version that I have and his software-center is working.

Is there something else I can try? Is there something that can be copied from his machine to mine?

Here's the output of *apt-cache policy software-center*:

```
software-center:
  Installed: 13.10-0ubuntu4.1+elementary2~ubuntu0.3.1
  Candidate: 13.10-0ubuntu4.1+elementary2~ubuntu0.3.1
  Version table:
 *** 13.10-0ubuntu4.1+elementary2~ubuntu0.3.1 0
        999 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     13.10-0ubuntu4.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     13.10-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

**11-23 Update**
I've been working with Ravan and we still haven't been able to get the issue resolved. Anyone else have something I haven't tried yet?

**12-2 Update**
Still have not found a solution to this issue. Does anyone another suggestion?

**12-11 Update**
After reinstalling the humanity and elementary icons I get the same error message except the top line has changed to:

```
** (software-center:1984): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-jF09oYYZXw: Connection refused
```

**12-15 Update**
Full output of new error message:

```
** (software-center:29012): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-jF09oYYZXw: Connection refused
2015-12-15 08:56:59,262 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 130, in <module>
    app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 407, in __init__
    self.icons)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/historypane.py", line 79, in __init__
    self._get_emblems(self.icons)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/historypane.py", line 199, in _get_emblems
    pb = icons.load_icon(emblem, self.ICON_SIZE, 0)
gi._glib.GError: Error opening file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please [edit] post and add output of `apt-cache policy software-center`

Comment: Any update regarding your problem?

Comment: I haven't had any luck getting the Elementary OS package manager working at this point and no one else has suggested a solution after Ravan worked with me. I've currently installed Synaptic Package Manager and am using that.

Comment: same problem, solution from Sneetsher worked

Answer (score 1):

You should have these icons in the current icon theme folder (`actions/16`):
`package-install`,`package-installed-locked`, `package-installed-outdated` & `package-installed-updated`.

Here are the default installed ones for Humanity & elementary theme.

```
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/actions/16/package-install.svg
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/actions/16/package-installed-locked.svg
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/actions/16/package-installed-outdated.svg
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/actions/16/package-installed-updated.svg
/usr/share/icons/elementary/actions/16/package-install.svg
/usr/share/icons/elementary/actions/16/package-installed-locked.svg
/usr/share/icons/elementary/actions/16/package-installed-outdated.svg
/usr/share/icons/elementary/actions/16/package-installed-updated.svg
```

So check if they exist then reinstall both themes:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall humanity-icon-theme elementary-icon-theme
```

I you are using a custom theme, copy them to its folder `/usr/share/icons/<theme-name>/actions/16/`

---

How i found this?

`software-center` is programmed in python (script). It can easily modified for debug. So added a line just before the trouble line (#199) to print the requested icon name.

```
    for i, emblem in enumerate(emblem_names):
        print("emblem:",emblem)
        pb = icons.load_icon(emblem, self.ICON_SIZE, 0)
```

Output on launching it in terminal: (NB: this is from a working copy)

```
('emblem:', 'package-install')
('emblem:', 'package-remove')
('emblem:', 'package-upgrade')
```

Comment: I don't want to blindly upvote your answer. Commenting here, so if OP solved his problem with your answer, I will come and give you upvote :D

Comment: This did not work but the first line of the error message did change, see above update.

Comment: @WinskiTech could you post the full output?

Comment: @WinskiTech, if you are comfortable with debugging, try add `print("emblem:",emblem)` line to `/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/historypane.py` then run it again in terminal and post the output. Also could you add output of `ls -l /usr/share/icons/elementary/actions/16/package-* /usr/share/icons/Humanity/actions/16/package-*`

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issues for the past few months with Freya 0.3.1. This was the final step in my repairs. The steps I did to finally resolve this issue was edited these files (take the time to make backups of each of these before starting these steps):

```
sudo mc
```

> Navigate to each of these files & using <kbd>F4</kbd>then editing the following files> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>keep file name the same.

## File list

#### `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
#### elementary OS PPA - http://www.elementaryos.com
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/daily/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/testing/ubuntu trusty main
```

#### `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list`

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu trusty main
```

#### `/etc/ls-release`

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu

DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04

DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty

DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
```

#### Changed to reflect elementary OS Freya

```
DISTRIB_ID="elementary OS"

DISTRIB_RELEASE=0.3.1

DISTRIB_CODENAME=freya

DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="elementary OS Freya"
```

#### `/etc/os-release`

```
NAME="Ubuntu"

VERSION="14.04.1 LTS, Trusty Tahr"

ID=ubuntu

ID_LIKE=debian

PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"

VERSION_ID="14.04"

HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"

SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"

BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

#### Changed to reflect Elementary OS Freya

```
NAME="elementary OS"

VERSION="0.3.2 Freya"

ID="elementary OS"

ID_LIKE=ubuntu

PRETTY_NAME="elementary OS Freya"

VERSION_ID="0.3.1"

HOME_URL="http://elementary.io/"

SUPPORT_URL="http://elementary.io/support/"

BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementary/+filebug"
```

Then I followed the steps here:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall humanity-icon-theme elementary-icon-theme
```

Now my Software Center works as it should. Hope this helps others and saves a great amount of time.

> WARNING . You can potential bork your entire system. I do not recommend attempting this repair without feeling comfortable with using the command line.

Comment: I fixed your post by adding formatting. I may have removed some important details so please review my edits

Comment: I think you should have a look at the markdown formatting guide : http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help . I write all my posts with correct formatting. Look @ http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/5117/3757 to see how I write in markdown

Comment: Thank you, I could not locate the editing help section yesterday.